# Understanding sessions and cookies

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, cookies, shopping-cart

I'm learning about sessions and cookies (also learning rails), and I came to wonder: why so many people have recommended me to store shopping car values in cookies or sessions if, when the session is over ( user logs out or cleans cookies manually), all the data about the shopping cart cease to exist? I want to remember those selected items, I think that when the connection is over, so is the data!
I think I'm misunderstanding something, because I thought that maybe we  can store that  shopping cart info in a database table, in which the key would be the user_id and it would be persistent.

This may be a silly question, so I'd be very grateful if someone  explained to me why,

Thanks!

Comment: shopping carts, depending on the application are stored in persistent memory too. It can be used for re targeting users, sending them notification email about their pending items in cart. it is generally depends on application design

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tutorials tend to use sessions and cookies for storage because it is simpler, but if you want long-term storage, a database is better.  With a website like Amazon, I can move from one computer to another and see my cart and wishlist - that is not possible with sessions or cookies.

Cookies are not secure, and sessions end, so those are not places to store long-term data.  Storing it server-side in a database gives you the most control over how it works.

Comment: Thanks a lot!  Now I get it. And also,  they say instead of using sessions or cookies to save large objects, sometimes we should save it in a database table, where the key is  _session_id_; do you happen to know any real life example of that object?

Comment: There are tons of tutorials online for creating a web app with a database.  Just do a search for something like "ruby database web application tutorial" and you'll find lots.  Any generic tutorial will do - you can apply the principles to your shopping cart application.  It's just about saving and retrieving data.  The only trick for the cart will be saving data for an anonymous user until he creates an account and has a userId, which is what you'll ultimately want to use.